# Get my application’s current path

Tags: c#

can someone tell me how to get the current path of my C# application; 
I need to load a DB , and I want my program get the DB from its own path, 
It’s something like GetEnviromentArgs , I don’t know.

Comment: is this on a web server or in a desktop application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

to get the execution folder:

```
System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location);
```

to get the current directory:

```
Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()
```

they aren't necessarily the same thing, so be careful

Comment: Great pal ; thank you